# Jquery make a mouseon / hover event for one element call / simulate a similar even for a different element?

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, simulation, mousehover

I'm using a plugin that is obscure and doesn't have a good API and, rather than digging around and re-writing it the way I want, I want to just use it the way its built which is that it has a list within a DIV and an action occurs based on moving the mouse over a list item in this DIV.. I want to simulate this so that I can make another action in the page do this, however I'm not sure exactly how to do this.. so far I have:

This gets the list element:

```
testit =  $('#masker').find('li').slice(0,1)
```

And I just found this on how to simulate but I'm not sure how to express the list element in this format since there is no ID or anything just a `<li>` within a DIV (so its going on the number of the `<li>` within the DIV

```
$("#element").hover(function(){
  //style some element(s) or do stuff.
});
```

EDIT:

I want to make it so, its something like this (when user hovers on Div id="mytestdiv" then it will call the action to simulate a hover on `<li>` #1 in "div id="masker"

```
$('#mytestdiv').mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);
```

calls this action

```
$('#masker').find('li').slice(0,1).hover(function(){
  //style some element(s) or do stuff.
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
$('#masker').find('li').slice(0,1).hover(function(){
  //style some element(s) or do stuff.
});
```

Comment: I made an edit, I want to make it so the action you gave is called by another action, I think I know how to do this part based on the info you gave so I will try that

Comment: this is what I was getting at, not sure if I worded the OP clearly enough, I can't seem to figure out how to do this properly:

I want to make it so, its something like this (when user hovers on Div id="mytestdiv" then it will call the action to simulate a hover on <li>  #1 in "div id="masker"

Comment: I suggest going through a jQuery tutorial it has a whole lot of those things. Select the element you want hovered over, then do `trigger('mouseover')`